# Get data from a list for a promoted links item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, list-view, promoted-links

I have a list with several columns, one of these columns is called "country". I also have promoted links with pictures of several countries.

Now what I want, is that when someone clicks on say, Belgium's picture on promoted links they get the results from the list which have "Belgium" chosen for the column "country".

Is this even possible to do? If not, is there some workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple solution in your situation is

- Passing the `Country name` in your URL as a **Query String** in the Promoted List.
- Using the **Query String Filter** web part to filter the current view with the country name.

  [image]

> **Note:** the URL should redirect to the list view with the Query string
>   like this
>
> ```
> ?Country=Egypt
> ```

Check also [Filter a List via URL Parameter in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/10/28/open-filter-list-url-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. But sadly I do not have "Filters" in my categories..